# sending data to a specific user id in socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Hii i am trying to write a function that sent a friend request to specific user by their id, but its not working. It not showing any error but its not working to a specific user.

Server file

```
socket.on("friendRequest", (friend) => {
      io.sockets.to(friend.receiver).emit("newFriendRequest", {
        from: friend.sender,
        to: friend.receiver
      });
      console.log("Reciever", friend.receiver)
    });
```

Client file that emiting event

```
  socket.emit("friendRequest", {
            receiver: id,
            sender: this.state.profile._id
        })
```

Another file that hold the new friend request on client side

```
  socket.on("newFriendRequest", (newRequest) => {
        setNewRequest([...newRquest, newRequest])
        console.log("Friend request sended", newRquest)
      })
```

Comment: Is `id` definitely the ID of a socket that exists? Try logging out the current sockets `io.sockets.clients()`

Comment: No its a specific user id that is generated in mongoDB

Comment: @JanardanPrajapti are you using MongoDB as a socket store?

Comment: No actually i don't know much about socket.io functionality. i am sending the data from a user to a specific user id and this id is generated by default in mongoDB. i am not using socket id because i don't know how to to that.

Comment: @JanardanPrajapti in that case `sockets.to(friend.receiver)` isn't going to work, socket.io would expect the client socket ID in here. You need to keep track of the socket IDs on the client / server in order to route the messages

Comment: Thank you can you please tell me how to do that?